# React Native TouchableHighlight onPress not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have tried everything to make this work. I have read all the answers and it never works for me. I am completely out of ideas.

Here is the function I am trying to call:

```
function handlePress() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

This one does nothing:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => { alert('You tapped the button!') }}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This one triggers without me doing anything:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={alert('You tapped the button!')}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This one triggers without me doing anything:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={handlePress()}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This one does nothing:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => {() => handlePress()}}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This one does nothing:

```
    <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => handlePress()}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This one does nothing:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={handlePress}>
  <Text style={ styles.sendButton }>Test Touch</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't you need to wrap the Text in a View? Do you see the highlight animation when you click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
   onPress={()=> {alert('You tapped the button!')}}>
  <Text style={{color: '#000', textAlign: "center", fontSize: 40}}>Test Touch</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

I just tried this one myself and it works. I didn't see a difference with your code, so I copied yours, tried and it worked. Are you sure you didn't mess up the CSS style making it unreachable?

I would isolate the button in some screen and try it alone.

Comment: I isolated it and it worked. I rewrote the class after that and now it's fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had done everything the same as you have. Only I have heavily relied on auto-import of VS code that TouchableHighlight was auto imported from `react-native-gesture-handler` rather it should be imported from `react-native` lib.

I changed it to `react-native` and it is working fine.

Wrong

[image]

Corrected

[image]